# How to get return values from solidity into javascript code?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, nft, erc-1155

I have been trying to write different solidity functions inside my smart contract trying to return different types of values:

```
uint256 public _currentTokenId = 0;

function getCurrentTokenId() public view returns (uint256){
        return _currentTokenId;
}
```

Using web3 in javascript I am unable to get this return value from the contract, instead, I get the transaction hash and contract details.

This is the javascript code:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const web3 = require("web3");
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

const MNEMONIC = process.env.MNEMONIC;
const NODE_API_KEY = process.env.INFURA_KEY || process.env.ALCHEMY_KEY;
const isInfura = !!process.env.INFURA_KEY;
const NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = process.env.ERC1155_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
const OWNER_ADDRESS = process.env.OWNER_ADDRESS;
const NETWORK = process.env.NETWORK;
const MINT_AMOUNT = 1;

if (!MNEMONIC || !NODE_API_KEY || !OWNER_ADDRESS || !NETWORK) {
  console.error(
    "Please set a mnemonic, Alchemy/Infura key, owner, network, and contract address."
  );
  return;
}

let tokenId = 0
  
const NFT_ABI = [
    {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "mintNFT",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "mintBatch",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getCurrentTokenId",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "_currentTokenId",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },    
];

async function main() {
  const network =
    NETWORK === "mainnet" || NETWORK === "live" ? "mainnet" : "rinkeby";
  const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    MNEMONIC,
    isInfura
      ? "https://" + network + ".infura.io/v3/" + NODE_API_KEY
      : "https://eth-" + network + ".alchemyapi.io/v2/" + NODE_API_KEY
  );
  const web3Instance = new web3(provider);

  if (NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS) {
    const nftContract = new web3Instance.eth.Contract(
      NFT_ABI,
      NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      { gasLimit: "1000000" }
    );
    console.log("CALLING NOW")
    nftContract.getCurrentTokenId(function(err,res){
      tokenId = res
      console.log(res)
    })
      console.log(tokenId);
  } else {
    console.error(
      "Add NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS or FACTORY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS to the environment variables"
    );
  }
}

main();
```

I have tried multiple things like .call and other things I saw online but there is still no proper return value received although it works on remix.

Are there any libraries I can use to effectively get the required return values?

Comment: What's web3 version? From the syntax it seems to be 0.20, in that case I suggest to use a more recent version 1.6.

Comment: "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.34" thats the version in the project in case that helps

Comment: Migrate to the new version web3 v1.6. The 1.0 version is no longer being supported.